# Setting up DHCP on RHEL8

Tags: rhel, dhcp

I am setting up a firewall/gateway router using rhel 8.
I have a server with two NICS, one public facing which is a dhcp client, the second NIC will be internal facing.  The first NIC is a Public zone, the second NIC is an Internal zone.
I would like to make the internal-facing NIC a DHCP server for internal clients.

I need to block my DHCP server from receiving DHCP requests on the public zone.

Question: Can you configure dhcp to be a server only for a specific NIC, or do you manage this with firewall rules to block all DHCP from the public zone? What is a good practice when setting up a multi-function gateway like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In RHEL 8, the `dhcpd.service` uses the `$DHCPDARGS` variable on the `ExecStart=` command line:

```
# /usr/lib/systemd/system/dhcpd.service
[Unit]
Description=DHCPv4 Server Daemon
Documentation=man:dhcpd(8) man:dhcpd.conf(5)
Wants=network-online.target
After=network-online.target
After=time-sync.target

[Service]
Type=notify
EnvironmentFile=-/etc/sysconfig/dhcpd
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/dhcpd -f -cf /etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf -user dhcpd -group dhcpd --no-pid $DHCPDARGS
StandardError=null

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

But the environment file `/etc/sysconfig/dhcpd` where such a variable would be defined has a warning, telling to not use that file anymore:

```
cat /etc/sysconfig/dhcpd 
# WARNING: This file is NOT used anymore.

# If you are here to restrict what interfaces should dhcpd listen on,
# be aware that dhcpd listens *only* on interfaces for which it finds subnet
# declaration in dhcpd.conf. It means that explicitly enumerating interfaces
# also on command line should not be required in most cases.

# If you still insist on adding some command line options,
# copy dhcpd.service from /lib/systemd/system to /etc/systemd/system and modify
# it there.
# https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Systemd#How_do_I_customize_a_unit_file.2F_add_a_custom_unit_file.3F

# example:
# $ cp /usr/lib/systemd/system/dhcpd.service /etc/systemd/system/
# $ vi /etc/systemd/system/dhcpd.service
# $ ExecStart=/usr/sbin/dhcpd -f -cf /etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf -user dhcpd -group dhcpd --no-pid <your_interface_name(s)>
# $ systemctl --system daemon-reload
# $ systemctl restart dhcpd.service
```

So apparently RHEL 8's ISC dhcpd has been patched to select the interfaces to listen on based on whether its configuration file includes subnet declarations for the interface or not. If there is no subnet declaration for a particular interface, it should not respond for that interface.

Because of how the DHCP protocol works on IPv4, `dhcpd` will need to use a raw socket (in order to be able to receive broadcast packets with source address 0.0.0.0 and destination 255.255.255.255, and also to send to 255.255.255.255 without being restricted by normal IPv4 routing), and so it needs to process its incoming packets more carefully anyway.

Because `dhcpd` uses raw sockets, it is also not affected by `iptables` firewalls.

If you still wish to add interface names on the command line, you can `cp /lib/systemd/system/dhcpd.service /etc/systemd/system/` and then modify the version in `/etc/systemd/system`, or just use `systemctl edit dhcpd.service` to create an override file. Of course, you'll need to remember that service files may have multiple `ExecStart=` lines, so in order to override the existing line instead of just adding another, you would run `systemctl edit dhcpd.service` and type in three lines:

```
[Service]
ExecStart=
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/dhcpd -f -cf /etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf -user dhcpd -group dhcpd --no-pid <your_interface_name(s)>
```

The first empty `ExecStart=` line tells systemd that you want to override the existing `ExecStart` definition in the service file rather than adding a second one.

If you use the `cp /lib/systemd/system/dhcpd.service /etc/systemd/system/` strategy, remember to run `systemctl daemon-reload` after modifying the `/etc/systemd/system/dhcpd.service` file.

If you use `systemctl edit dhcpd.service`, it will run the equivalent of `systemctl daemon-reload` for you automatically.

Comment: I tried this out and it worked perfectly. I just had to have interfaces on different subjects and update dhcp.conf as you suggested. Such a simple solution. When used with network zones I can easily configure firewall rules for each subnet.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on which particular dhcp daemon you're using but yes, it's possible to either configure a dhcp daemon to give different answers depending on which interface the dhcp/bootp request came from **or** to run multiple instances of the dhcpd, each one configured to listen only on one interface.

In your case, it sounds like you just want to tell your dhcpd to listen only on your private LAN interface.  If you're using ISC dhcpd, you can do that just by adding the name(s) of  the interface(s) you want it to listen on to the dhcpd command line.

e.g. on my system, I want dhcpd to listen only on my wireless (`wifi0`) and internal network (`br0` - I use a bridged interface because it's convenient for running VMs) interfaces, so I run it as:

```
/usr/sbin/dhcpd -4 -q -cf /etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf br0 wlan0
```

Comment: Awesome. Thank you. I’ll try it out.  One question. Are those options available if dhcp is started by systemctl?

Comment: I have one more question. What do you do if you have multiple NICs and you want a different dhcp subnet for each NIC? Do you run multiple dhcpd processes? (Each with their own dhcp.conf? Thanks